# Play: Accessing Current request from Async Job

Tags: playframework

I'm just getting a hang of using Jobs for long running tasks.
Jobs are run on a seperate thread, therefore I cannot access any ThreadLocal variables like the current Request or the information like the current user. I could as a solution pass them as constructor arguments, but this feels to mee a bit un-PlayFramework-ish.

Does Play framework allow me to retrieve this information in some way? Or is the constructor sollution the only way to do this?

/Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a set of public variables in your job. Initialiaze/init the job with those and then launch the job.